# Heroku latency issues

Tags: heroku

We've been having trouble with database query times on our Heroku app, and I've set up a new test app with a script that pings our MongoLab db server and Google. The MongoLab db server is in the same datacenter as the Heroku app.

The RTT to the db server is approximately 3ms. Now, even on the test server, I am seeing a great amount of jitter. You can see the output of my ping script here: http://damp-citadel-6004.herokuapp.com/test - the latency fluctuates frequently into the 30ms range, and sometimes even into the 100s of ms range.

I'm just wondering if this is normal behavior for Heroku? If it is, Heroku will no longer be a viable option as we need low latency for the MongoLab connection. The current amount of latency is killing our app because of the time added to queries.

The Heroku stack is Cedar and it is located in US-EAST, as is the MongoLab db.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious how you know your heroku dynos are in the same datacenter as mongolab's instances? By ip somehow? Can you really be sure? Both of those services use multiple availability zones in the us-east-1 AWS region, and as far as I know don't let you specify a preference or report where resources reside. 2 heroku dynos for the same app might, and from the sounds of it probably do live in different AWS AZs. It's certainly true that different AZs reside in different datacenters, and I believe even that some availability zones span multiple datacenters.

Anyways, you're not the only one. I have had frequent connectivity issues lately from both heroku and my own ec2 instances to both mongolab and mongohq in the same Amazon region as well. Mongohq support echoed that they have also been having connectivity issues between EC2 instances in different AZs in us-east-1 and hinted that AWS support had acknowledged some network level/security group scaling issues of late. I was able to find this article: http://orensol.com/2009/05/24/network-latency-inside-and-across-amazon-ec2-availability-zones/ which suggests that the latencies you're observing are exceptionally high.

Perhaps relatedly, I have also experienced problems with DNS resolvers within EC2 -- heroku included -- to mongolab and mongohq. Even for route 53 zones for which the authoritative servers all belong to amazon. All in all, it seems that connectivity between availability zones in us-east-1 isn't at 100% right now so while I'd encourage you to experiment with other EC2 based database services, you may not see any difference.

Comment: This should be just a comment, or should be consolidated down to something more useful.